# make an intent from an object onstead of a class

Tags: android, gps, android-intent

I'm trying to make an intent by sending an object instead of a class. 
instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EXGPS.this, LocationGPS.class);
```

I need:

```
LocationGPS gps = new LocationGPS(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(EXGPS.this, gps);
```

I have to do it in some way cause I cant pass my LocationGPS  contructor that is getting Context c.
thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way.  Set up a `Global` class which has a static reference to your `Application`'s `Context`.  Reference that static field directly from your `LocationGPS` class.